# FloatField (TextField for floats in javafx)?

Tags: java, javafx

Is there such thing as a FloatField in java fx. I need to be able to write and edit floats. So I tested it using strings. But setCellProperty doesn't support floats

```
TableColumn<Dish, Float> costCol = new TableColumn<>("Price");
costCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Dish, Float>("cost"));


costCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<Dish>forTableColumn());
```

Comment: Why not just use a string text field and check that the user input can be parsed as a float before doing anything with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generic type for the `TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn()` method is the *column type* (`Float` in this case), not the table type.

Assuming your `Dish` class has a `costProperty()` method returning the appropriate type, your code will work if you provide a converter to the [`forTableColumn`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/TextFieldTableCell.html#forTableColumn-javafx.util.StringConverter-) method:

```
costCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(new FloatStringConverter()));
```

(In Java 8, the complier will infer the correct generic type in the code above; if you want to be explicit you would do `TextFieldTableCell<Float>.forTableColumn(...)`.)